# Wanted to hide info dynamically when there is only one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

Wanted to hide the info option in DOM when there is only one page shown. I achieved it on paging but cannot find a solution to do the same on info option.

I have used this to hide paging option when only 1 page is present.

```
preDrawCallback: function (settings) {
$(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate').toggle((new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings)).page.info().pages > 1); }
```

Help me out. Thanks. Info means this ->("Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries")

Comment: share `html` part also

Comment: @SatyamPathak actually I'm using customReport to generate a html for different report. So it has no data related to the table.

Comment: One can able to solve the problem when he gets/understand the problem. So please share anything which get reproducible

Comment: it still generate some html template, without that, we dont know what u actually handle

Comment: here I have made a example. Here you see the ("Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries") I just want to hide that when there is only 1 page and show when  there is more.[link](https://jsfiddle.net/8u2kg60b/1/) @Se0ng11

Comment: what is the id of your table?

Comment: Solved the problem check below answers. thanks @AlokMali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let maxRowSize = 4;
$('#example').data( "page-length", maxRowSize);
let table = $('#example').DataTable();
if(table.column(0).data().length / maxRowSize == 1) {
    $('#example_paginate').toggle("example_paginate");
}
});
```

Comment: It hides the paginate not the info which I'm asking about. Read the question carefully

Comment: Then simply change it for what you need to hide. In your case it will be `$('#example_info').toggle("example_info");`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I used this to hide both dynamically.
$(document).ready(function() {
    let maxRowSize = 4;
$('#example').data( "page-length", maxRowSize);
let table = $('#example').DataTable();
if(table.column(0).data().length / maxRowSize == 1) {
    $('#example_info').toggle("example_info");
    $('#example_paginate').toggle("example_paginate");
}
});

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved my using this in code.

```
preDrawCallback: function (settings) {
            $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_info').toggle((new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings)).page.info().pages > 1); 
            $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate').toggle((new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings)).page.info().pages > 1); 
            }
```

Thanks for your help.